# Is now the time to start designing for 1280px wide screens instead of 1024px?

Tags: css, screen-resolution

Need opinions on this, what do you guys think? A good idea or not so good idea.

I could do a seperate css style but not sure whether to drop 1024 for sure.

Comment: I know what you're asking, but could you revise the question to be a little more specific, please? For the sake of being a "good question"

Comment: Not really related to programming, and it depends somewhat on your target audience. That said, I design for 1024 whenever I can.

Comment: 1024 is still a default resolution on some computers being purchased, but it's definitely on its way out.

Comment: Nowadays you can tilt your wide monitors, so you actually get 1200 on some (1200x1920). Next step would be 1200, not 1280 :)

Comment: FWIW we're pretty much prepped to drop 1024 here too. But we have a lot of graphics that need to be migrated over to a more fluid format (HTML5 FTW) before we will be quite ready to drop 1024...

Comment: @Joel +1, I was writing up a small dissertation on the mobile and tablet device scenes, but this is now closed. Ah well :-)

Comment: Here's a great Google tool that shows which parts of your page are above the fold for general population: http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/  Docs: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/12/introducing-google-browser-size.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where you're coming from, and I think we're getting close.  But I wouldn't do a blanket drop on 1024 just yet.  It depends on your audience, really.  A lot of conference room projectors still max at 1024, a lot of older web surfers still keep it at 1024 because it's easier to read, a lot of smaller devices with "full web browsers" still run at 1024 (or something close to it).

It's really a weighted decision, for any individual project, between the target audience and the effect in user experience of a horizontal scroll (or unexpected wrapping).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't drop it just yet. A lot of people still run 1024. I have two monitors at work, both set to 1024. It is a great source of annoyance when websites are too wide for the screen, and if it's really bad, I just don't go back (especially if it's a non-essential site).

As others have said it depends on your target audience. Here in this corporate world I'm in, your 1280 site would be very unpopular with most of the users here. Until there's a mass-upgrade which pushes most of us up to 1280. If there's a way to keep it flexible and work at multiple widths, that is usually best, but I know that can also make things rather difficult.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your website.  What is it about? Who is your audience?  I have designed and implemented websites for a number of different topics.  For example, if you are designing a furniture site, you are probably going to want to keep the resolution down because the audience you are going for can be any age, any browser, and their computer could be older than dinosaurs.

Another example, if its a tech or gameing site than you are probably ok to use a higher rez as that type of audience probably keeps their equipment nearly upto modern resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever someone asks me this type of questions I always say..

It depends on your audience. Try using trackig tools like Google Analytics to see what resolution/browser versions your users are using and then change it to suit the majority of the users.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it really depends on the demographic of your target audience.

Let's say you're putting a site together targeted at gamers. Chances are that most people looking at that site have high resolution capable monitors, so it'd be safe (again, imo) to design at a higher res.

However, if you're developing a site or system that you don't want to turn *anyone* away from (i.e. commercial shopping or social networking type of site), then you really want to develop for the lowest common denominator. If someone stops visiting your site because it's annoying to them that it doesn't fit in their browser, that's one less customer.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm

I know that 76% have over 1024 resolution (January 2010 browser display stats - w3schools.com), but 20% still use 1024 x 768.

Designing a site around 1280 will annoy people with a smaller rez, and having to scroll horizontal to view content is not good, users will just leave and go elsewhere if they have to constantly horizontal scroll.

It's going to depend on your target audience though. Also think about how popular portable devices are becoming now, such as the iPhone, iPad...? How will a site designed for 1280 preform on those?

Of course you could always create specific mobile type sites for smaller screen size portable devices.

For now I still stick with the 960 width grid system :)

Comment: Yea currently im making 2 stylesheets, one for 960 and another something else can't remember the exact width lol.